# Protractor/Jasmine how to get the correct spec result status

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have below spec, in the **afterEach**, I defined a variable to verify the spec result status, and want to do something according it.
After execute the the expected false spec, I found the variable didnot return the correct result.

```
describe('test suite', function() {
  afterEach(function (done) {
    var failedStatus = (this.status == 'failed');
    //do sth with the variable failedStatus
    console.log(failedStatus);
  });

  it('should be a failed', function() {
    expect(false).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

In above, I expect the failedStatus should be True, but it return False.
How to correct it? 
Thank you.

Comment: Have you defined a variable called `status` somewhere and using it `this.status`? Can you show that implementation? Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur , I didnot defined it. Does "this" has the status property could automatically verify the spec result status?

Comment: `this` always refers to current context that you calling it in, in your case it refers to your function. In order to get correct spec result check this - http://jasmine.github.io/edge/custom_reporter.html. Hope it helps.

Comment: @GirishSortur  very thanks for the tips. it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** - in your base configuration you should add custom reporter and call specDone which collects the data of this specific spec.

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
        specDone:function (result) {
            console.log("spec name:"+ result.fullName);
            console.log("result:"+ result.status);
            console.log("id:"+ result.id);
            console.log("description:"+ result.description);
        }
    });
```

according to documentation,The capabilities are:

```
interface CustomReporterResult {
    description: string;
    failedExpectations?: FailedExpectation[];
    fullName: string;
    id: string;
    passedExpectations?: PassedExpectation[];
    pendingReason?: string;
    status?: string;
}
```

For more info you can read the full documentation: [link](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_reporter)